# React Native Debugger Error - Cannot GET /debugger-ui/

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native Debugger is automatically loading to http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/.

However, I keep getting the following error -

`Cannot GET /debugger-ui/`

Comment: I have this issue, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently they have left a bug in the code. For it to work right now, you will have to change the react-native-community module on your own.

Go to the file

> /node_modules/react-native-community/cli/build/commands/server/middleware/MiddlewareManager.js

and, in the line 97

> const debuggerUIFolder = _path().default.join(__dirname, '..', 'util',
>   'debugger-ui');

remove the **'util'** param, changing it to

> const debuggerUIFolder = _path().default.join(__dirname, '..',
>   'debugger-ui');

Comment: Just as info, as of today, I got the same error. Checked the lines you refer to and bug's not there anymore. I had to reinstall `node_modules` and `--reset-chache` as @P.Lorand wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55950649/3157057). Didn't need 3rd step though.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was only:

1. `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`
2. `npm run start -- -- reset-cache`
3. `cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install`